# Octave value dimensions

Tags: c++, octave

I'm using Octave in c++ code. I'm trying to figure out the dimensions of every element of `out`

```
octave_value_list out = feval (q, in, 1);
```

I used

```
dim_vector x=out(0).dims();
```

According to dim-vector.h, it can only support up to 7 dimensions. Is there any way I can get the rows, columns and pages for every element of `out`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there is need to correct a mistake on your premises:

> According to dim-vector.h, it can only support up to 7 dimensions.

Not true.  What the header says is that there are constructors for only up to 7 dimensions. Above that, you'll have to increase the number of dimensions and set their lengths yourself.

Compare the following which are equivalent:

```
// create dim_vector for 5x5x5 array
dim_vector d1 = dim_vector (5, 5, 5);

dim_vector d2 = dim_vector ();

dim_vector d3 = d2.redim (3);
d3(2) = 5;
d2.resize (3, 5);
```

To generate dim_vectors above 7 dimensions, you can:

```
// 10 dimensional dim_vector of size 5x5x5...x5
dim_vector d = dim_vector ();
d.resize (10, 5);
```

See [doxygen dev docs for dim_vector](http://octave.org/doxygen/4.1/d1/db1/classdim__vector.html#details). They are more complete on the current development sources.

---

Now, to answer your specific question

> Is there any way I can get the rows, columns and pages for every element of out?

Just index the dim_vector you get out of each `octave_value` in the `octave_value_list`

```
octave_value_list out = feval (q, in, 1);
for (octave_idx_type out_i = 0; out_i < out.length (); out_++)
  {
    dim_vector d = out(out_i).dims ();
    for (octave_idx_type di = 0 ; di < d.length (); di++)
      std::cout << "Length of dimension " << di << ": " << d(di) << std:endl;
  }
```